# Sanitize and Paginate

Tags: cakephp, sql-injection

I was just reading that in newer versions of Cake, the Sanitize class will be removed.  I'm using CakePHP 2.3 in which it I believe is already deprecated.  Normally I'd use prepared statements for the query I'm trying to write, but I don't believe that's possible while using the paginate Component.  ultimately I will be paginating the results, but here's the options I have so far for the query:

```
$options = array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => '(SELECT search_terms.name, product_search_terms.product_id AS product_id_1
                             FROM product_search_terms
                             JOIN search_terms ON search_terms.id = product_search_terms.search_term_id                          
                             )',
                    'alias' => 'SearchTerm',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'SearchTerm.product_id_1 = Product.id',
                        'LOWER(SearchTerm.name) REGEXP "[[:<:]]' . $word . '[[:>:]]"', //Here's the line that is vulnerable
                    )
                )
            ),
            'fields' => array('Product.id', 'SearchTerm.name'),
        );
```

The line 'LOWER(SearchTerm.name) REGEXP "[[:<:]]' . $word . '[[:>:]]"', is surely vulnerable to SQL injection.  Can this be prevented without using Sanitize or prepared statements?

Comment: Are you sure, the class still there, i always add to my appController

$this->request->data   = Sanitize::clean($this->request->data);
$this->request->query  = Sanitize::clean($this->request->query);
$this->request->params = Sanitize::clean($this->request->params);

Comment: I don't believe the class has been removed (they plan on doing that in cake 2.4), but I'd prefer to make my code up to date if possible.  Guess I'll stick to the old way then.

Comment: The class will be removed in 3.0 (not before, it is merely marked deprecated until then). See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html for that and how to work with other tools that will accomplish the same.